# 2 Identical Programs; Only 1 asks for elevation

Tags: c++, mingw, uac, codeblocks

I am having an interesting problem when compiling my programs on win32 (mingw).
I have 2 identical projects, both created in C::B. When compiling one, it runs just fine without requiring elevated permissions, but the other prompts the user with the "Allow program to make changes to computer etc.." dialog. I would like the app to not prompt the user, as it does not need elevated privs.

This is under Win7 x64.

Could this be a Code::Blocks issue, or a compiler issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the programs really identical (for example, does md5sum return the same value on both)? It may be that you have a manifest embedded in one, and not in the other.

Comment: No, the MD5 is different on the 2 files :/
However I dont see how a manifest could have been embeded; they were both started as new projects and the code was copied and pasted from the first to the second.

Comment: Solved!
Windows 7 marks anything with "update" in the name as something that needs Admin privileges. 
I did not expect this. But renaming files to random strings seems to work better than useful, descriptive names.....

Comment: @Dylan: I think you should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Yep, that is definitively worth knowing.

Comment: Windows 7 (or Vista) uses certain methods to try to guess if programs should require elevation (as a means of compatibility with older programs). Among the methods, it seems catch if the program name or version resources contain words like "setup", "install", or "update".  Here's a previous question that answers how to solve it without renaming: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533939/how-to-prevent-vista-from-requiring-elevation-on-patch-exe

Comment: I can self answer in 7 hours (some sort of reputation limit as I have <100).
Looks like I have to wait until then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out Win7 marks files with "update" (not case sensitive) in the name as needing elevated permissions. So yea, worth knowing for future

Comment: Also file names like 'setup' or 'install' I think also require elevated permissions.

Comment: And "patch", which is particularly annoying for those of us with a Win32 version of the coreutils tool :(

Answer (score 1):

As you have already discovered, Windows detects certain application names that it thinks are setup programs, and tries to helpfully pre-elevate them to ensure they succeed.

However, this behaviour is only enabled for executables that are missing UAC information in their Win32 manifest. So if you have a program with one of the impacted names, simply give it a manifest with the relevant UAC information, and you won't get the unwanted prompts.

e.g. Aaron's blog http://brethorsting.com/blog/2007/02/meet_uac_-_creating_a_uac_manifest/

Martyn