# Applying a .patch to .py files in Windows 7

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, patch

Alright, so I want to change a file in Google App Engine, and there is a patch for it provided at the following link:

[Issue 4849 on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=4849)

I can see that the .patch files modify a particular .py fie on my HD, but am unable to make any changes myself since I do not know how to use .patch files. I have searched online, BUT SOMEHOW, there seems to be NO data on applying a patch on a .py file in windows. Can someone please help me?

**Or better still, can someone simply apply the patch on the _*init.py*_ file and send it over? (I am not being lazy, I just don't think it's smart to type in so much about finding a patch software on windows if someone can do it readily on linux)**

Here are the patch files and the **init**.py files: It'sa 5 KB rar file!

[**init**.rar](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/37517156/__init__.rar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [patch.exe for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm), then run the following command in a directory containing both `__init__.patch` and `__init__.py` (from the rar you attached to your question).

```
path\to\patch.exe -p4 < __init__.patch
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517257/how-do-i-apply-a-diff-patch-on-windows) for alternatives.

That should produce the following output

```
patching file __init__.py
```

Comment: Thank you! The files are named __init__.py and __init__.patch - where does this information go in? I can see the first part to be patch.exe but cannot figure out what the second part of the command line is.

Comment: updated the answer w/ proper instruction for the attached files.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update and the help. However, using the program gives me the output that "The program has requested to be terminated in an unusual way". What could be the reason?

Comment: try renaming `patch.exe` into `hop.exe` before running it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914180/windows-7-exe-filename-starts-with-patch-wont-run

Comment: I have used Tortoise, but it does nothing. I don't understand, but the software just hangs - says it is fetching the original file or something, and keeps displaying that dialog box.

Comment: Attached the patched `__init__.py` to the issue for convenience http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4849