# svn client 1.4.4 any hope in applying a patch?

Tags: svn, diff, patch

I am stuck using an old svn client 1.4.4. I was able to create a patch using the standard approach of piping to a file:

```
svn diff > ~/bug_fix.diff
```

Is there any hope in applying this patch? I see that there is no "svn patch" sub-command in this version.

Would it be possible to use a newer client to apply the patch without breaking compatibility with 1.4.4?

Comment: Tried using a new version and got a stupid upgrade error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cygwin ended up being the solution here for me:

```
diff -N -x .svn -rup ./original_trunk ./new_trunk > patch.diff
```

cd to ./original_trunk

```
patch -p0 < ../patch.diff
```

original trunk should now have the changes from new trunk.

Hardest part about this is getting the diff and patch utilities installed in cygwin. I installed the patch utility using apt-cyg and diff I found in the cygwin installer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any hope in applying this patch?

It *can be* compatible with ordinary OS `patch` command

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you would do this on windows?

Comment: @RyanR. - on one of my system I have Unixtools (old, very old port with small subset of native Linux-commands), on other - [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki)

Answer (score 1):

Apply subversion diff file by using the patch utility ([or patch.exe on windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm).)

```
patch -p0 < ~/bug_fix.diff
```

*or*

```
patch.exe -p0 < ~/bug_fix.diff
```

Comment: tried to install the patch.exe program referenced. Won't run on my windows 7 box. Just hangs when the exe is launched. Tried a manual install and the 'installer'. Trying to diagnose further if it is a dll dependency issue or what seems like a nightmare. Found a reference to patch programs needing elevated permissions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533939/how-to-prevent-vista-from-requiring-elevation-on-patch-exe. Ran inside of a elevated terminal though without success.